# Expectation calculation at infinity

Tags: expectation

While reading a paper, i came across  the following Expectations:

Given that the $E\left\{e^2_{n-i-1}e^2_{n-j-1}\right\}=E\left\{e^2_{n-i-1}\right\}E\left\{e^2_{n-j-1}\right\}$ for $i\neq j$.\

Then as $n\rightarrow\infty$

$E\left\{\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-2}\alpha^i e^2(n-i-1)\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-2}\alpha^i e^2(n-i-1)\right)\right\}=\frac{2\alpha\left(E\left( e_\infty^2\right)\right)^2}{(1-\alpha)^2(1+\alpha)}+\frac{E\left( e_\infty^4\right)}{(1-\alpha^2)}$.

Can you provide me with proof or any hint/help? I tried but couldn't get the same answer.Thanks

Comment: You problem seems to be somewhat "algebraic" in nature. Posting your scratch work is *how* we can identify error in reasoning. Otherwise you may get a spoon feed solution or a wild guess at the root cause of your struggles.